# IllegalArgumentException Error in Clojure

Tags: clojure, illegalargumentexception

I get this error:

> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)

when I call this function:

```
    (defn my-butlast [lista]
      (loop [c lista
             last ()]
        (if (= (count c) 1)
          last
          (recur (concat last (first c))
                 (pop c)))))
```

The function should return a list with the same elements as its input list but excluding the last element, or '()' if it's empty.

And the error only happens when the list has two or more elements like this:

```
(my-butlast '(a b))
```

Answer (score 2):

`concat`: "concatenation of the elements in the supplied **colls**" (taken from https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat). Your error seems to be consistent with not passing `concat` the correct argument types. You could try using `conj` in place of `concat`, or else wrapping the second argument to `concat` in a `vector`.

If you choose `conj` be sure to understand the different behavior between `conj`-ing onto a `list` verses onto a `vector`: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a diferent approach, a bit simpler in my opinion. Try something like `(reverse (rest (reverse list)))`.

If that's all you need, no need to complicate. If you actually have a reason why you started like that, just read a bit about `concat`, that's where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `concat` only takes `collections`.

Here is the offending expression:
`(concat last (first c))`

Have a look at these links as they provide some useful techniques in order to help debug your Clojure code:

[REPL DEBUGGING: NO STACKTRACE REQUIRED](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2017/6/5/repl-debugging-no-stacktrace-required)

[Debugging with the Scientific Method - Stuart Halloway](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBxs_k3-jVAhWHAMAKHUs-AYgQtwIIKzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DFihU5JxmnBg&usg=AFQjCNFuwZ2AJKhM2tVd89MK0EZ9iHVrYg)